# The following From address failed: xxxx@example.com: Called Mail() without being connected

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I' am getting this error message on WordPress trying to send SMTP mail.

```
The following From address failed: xxxx@example.com: Called Mail() without being connected
```

This is the code I have in placed

```
 include_once( ABSPATH . "/wp-includes/class-phpmailer.php");
                $mail = new PHPMailer();
                $mail->IsSMTP();
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
                $mail->Host       = $host;
                $mail->Username   = $username;
                $mail->Password   = $pass;
                $mail->Port       = $port;
                $mail->SMTPSecure = 'none';
                $mail->SetFrom($email);
                $mail->AddAddress("email@example.com");
                $mail->Subject = "Contact Us Form";
                $mail->MsgHTML("")
```

Comment: did you replace the variables such as $host, $username etc..?

Comment: Yes I did but still it doesn't work. Let me try again...

Comment: Still doesn't work...hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code as follows as per [PhPMailer example](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp):

```
require_once('../class.phpmailer.php'); //make sure this path is correct
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic with authentication";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```